# команды linux debian

Tags: linux, debian, grep, ram

С помощью каких команд можно узнать:

1. *архитектуру ПК*
2. *модель процессора*
3. *количество памяти, которая уже не используется процессами, но ещё остаётся в памяти (inactive)*
   Предполагается конструкция ***"{команда} | grep {параметр для фильтрации вывода}"***

Comment: несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Архитектура ПК:

   uname -m
2. Модель процессора:

   cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | uniq
3. Количество inactive памяти:

   cat /proc/meminfo | grep Inactive

Comment: спасибо огромное!!

Comment: uname -i не архитектура пк)

Comment: кстати, да. этак команда не работает.

Comment: lscpu подойдет?

Comment: извиняюсь, сработает: uname -m

Comment: Уж сколько раз твердили миру... *Useless use of cat*.